# What version of freetype does Maverick use?

Tags: 10.10

The short of it: what version of libfreetype does Maverick use? I'm currently using Lucid and it has libfreetype6 2.3.11.

The long of it: I'm having trouble with freetype errors when trying to compile Wine, and since I've read that upgrading to a newer version of freetype might fix the problem, I wanted to do that, but I realized that I'm due for an upgrade from Lucid to Maverick, and maybe that'll indirectly fix my freetype errors.

Answer (score 2):

It's [libfreetype6 2.4.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype)